# Can't boot into any Live USB - Black screen

Tags: boot

I have Windows 8 laptop and I installed Ubuntu Mate 15 in parallel with windows. But now I want to install either Mint or Debian in place of Mate but I can't boot into any Live USB. As soon as the grub loads and I choose to install Mint or Debian, the screen blacks out and nothing happens. I even tried `nomodeset` but that didn't help either.

The Ubuntu Mate live USB still works, Linux Mint blacks out and Debian does not even boot from USB. I tried using Universal USB installer and UNETBOOTIN both have same result. What could be the issue?

Graphic: Intel 7620

Comment: A few questions: Did you verify the hash sum of the downloaded iso image file? Can you check whether your stick works on other machines? Can you select the stick from your UEFI boot menu?

Comment: @ByteCommander, MD5 is correct and I can boot on other machines. Also I can pick the USB stick from UEFI list.

Comment: And what happens if you boot it from UEFI and not from GRUB? Does it still show the same problem?

Comment: @ByteCommander, found the problem. I disabled the `Secure Boot` and it was booted in legacy mode. Now it works. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Mint and Debian are off-topic here as well. However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

@ByteCommander: FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem could be solved by disabling the **Secure Boot** option and booting in **legacy mode**.

<sub>This answer is written just to give the questioner the possibility of marking the problem as solved. If anybody can and wants to improve this post by adding additional detail, please do it. That's the purpose of a community-wiki answer.

@norbertpy: Please accept this as answer!</sub>